# GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/profiles/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

i am using vuejs and laravel as backend and i have a form which stores user avatar pic in storage and i am trying to show the image in front end in profile page of user using vuejs and i am able to display the avatar pic of user in front end but in console i get `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/profiles/ 404 (Not Found)` error though its showing avatar pic in frontend.

what i did in frontend part to display user avatar pic is:

```
<img class="img-circle" :src="getProfilePhoto()" alt="User Avatar">

getProfilePhoto(){
    let photo = this.form.photo.indexOf('base64') != -1 ? this.form.photo : 'storage/profiles/'+this.form.photo;
    return photo;
}
```

Comment: Is your HTTP Server up & running? Is this route correct & defined?

Comment: Can you post your route file for this route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point `this.form.photo` is an empty string. The browser makes a request to the URL, gets a 404 error, and renders a missing image.

Then the value of `this.form.photo` changes, which triggers a rerender, which runs the function again, changes the `src` to the new value and renders an actual image.

You need to account for the possibility that `this.form.photo` isn't set.

For example, you could:

```
getProfilePhoto(){
    let photo = "/static/default-profile.png";
    if (this.form.photo) {
        if (this.form.photo.indexOf('base64') != -1) {
            photo = this.form.photo;
        } else {
            photo = 'storage/profiles/' + this.form.photo;
        }
    }
    return photo;
}
```

Comment: thankyou so so much it fixed my issue i initialize photo with some static pic and it fixed my issue. i hope this answer will be helpful to someone in future :-)